# Error while using Vgg16 (transfter learning) - RuntimeError: Failed to run torchinfo

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to use VGG16 with transfer learning, but getting errors:

```
model = torchvision.models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
print(model)
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

input_size             = model.classifier[0].in_features    
model.classifier[0]   = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(input_size, 128), nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(128, 2))

torchinfo.summary(model, (64, 3, 224, 224))
```

VGG16:

```
VGG(
  (features): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (3): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (4): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (5): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (6): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (7): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (8): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (9): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (10): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (12): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (13): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (14): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (15): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (16): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (17): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (18): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (19): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (20): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (21): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (22): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (23): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (24): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (25): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (26): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (27): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (28): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (29): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (30): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  )
  (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(7, 7))
  (classifier): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=25088, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
    (3): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (4): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (5): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
    (6): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1000, bias=True)
  )
)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchinfo/torchinfo.py in forward_pass(model, x, batch_dim, cache_forward_pass, device, **kwargs)
    260             if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)):
--> 261                 _ = model.to(device)(*x, **kwargs)
    262             elif isinstance(x, dict):

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/models/vgg.py in forward(self, x)
     51         x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
---> 52         x = self.classifier(x)
     53         return x

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1119 
-> 1120         result = forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1121         if _global_forward_hooks or self._forward_hooks:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py in forward(self, input)
    140         for module in self:
--> 141             input = module(input)
    142         return input

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1119 
-> 1120         result = forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1121         if _global_forward_hooks or self._forward_hooks:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
    102     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 103         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    104 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1847         return handle_torch_function(linear, (input, weight, bias), input, weight, bias=bias)
-> 1848     return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
   1849 

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (64x2 and 4096x4096)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_8204/406510959.py in <module>
     11     nn.Linear(128, 2))
     12 
---> 13 torchinfo.summary(model, (64, 3, 224, 224))

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchinfo/torchinfo.py in summary(model, input_size, input_data, batch_dim, cache_forward_pass, col_names, col_width, depth, device, dtypes, row_settings, verbose, **kwargs)
    192         input_data, input_size, batch_dim, device, dtypes
    193     )
--> 194     summary_list = forward_pass(
    195         model, x, batch_dim, cache_forward_pass, device, **kwargs
    196     )

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchinfo/torchinfo.py in forward_pass(model, x, batch_dim, cache_forward_pass, device, **kwargs)
    268     except Exception as e:
    269         executed_layers = [layer for layer in summary_list if layer.executed]
--> 270         raise RuntimeError(
    271             "Failed to run torchinfo. See above stack traces for more details. "
    272             f"Executed layers up to: {executed_layers}"

RuntimeError: Failed to run torchinfo. See above stack traces for more details. Executed layers up to: [Sequential: 1, Conv2d: 2, ReLU: 2, Conv2d: 2, ReLU: 2, MaxPool2d: 2, Conv2d: 2, ReLU: 2, Conv2d: 2, ReLU: 2, MaxPool2d: 2, Conv2d: 2, ReLU: 2, Conv2d: 2, ReLU: 2, Conv2d: 2, ReLU: 2, MaxPool2d: 2, Conv2d: 2, ReLU: 2, Conv2d: 2, ReLU: 2, Conv2d: 2, ReLU: 2, MaxPool2d: 2, Conv2d: 2, ReLU: 2, Conv2d: 2, ReLU: 2, Conv2d: 2, ReLU: 2, MaxPool2d: 2, AdaptiveAvgPool2d: 1, Sequential: 2, Linear: 3, ReLU: 3, Linear: 3, ReLU: 2, Dropout: 2]
```

I'm using the following pytorch packages versions:

```
torch==1.10.0
torchinfo==1.5.3
torchvision==0.11.1
```

1. What is wrong ?
2. WHat do I need to change in order to use VGG16 (with transfer learning) ?

Comment: I see `RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (64x2 and 4096x4096)` in the logs so you might mismatch dimension when changing model.classifier[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're trying to change the final classifier, you should change the whole, not only one layer:

```
model.classifier   = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(input_size, 128), nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(128, 2))
```